# Marketing Cloud double opt-in process

Tags: marketing-cloud, subscriber, email-studio

I’m trying to understand how to configure a double opt-in classic scenario with Lists.

Am I right about the sequence of actions in the main scenario below?

Step 1: A subscriber sends a blank email to a specified email address

Step 2: Marketing Cloud adds the subscriber in All Subscribers list and Double opt-in list with “Unsubscribed” status.

Step 3: Subscriber clicks the link and activates himself (“Active” Status) in All Subscribers list and Double opt-in list.

Keeping in mind this scenario, I have a couple of questions:

1. There is no “Double Opt-In tab” in any List (new and existing, simply one step to create it and possibility to check that it is public). I’m referring to this doc.: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_create_list.htm&type=5 FYI: I activated the “Double Opt-In” feature in Setup -> Feature Settings -> Email Studio
2. It is not clear the process of sending a blank email on behalf of a new subscriber. Any details there? To which email address? How to configure it?
   Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why this step? *Step 1: A subscriber sends a blank email to a specified email address*

Comment: @LukasLunow In the document, it is said: “The double opt-in campaign process begins when the subscriber sends a blank email to the specified email address.” https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_blank_double_optin_email.htm&language=fr&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5#:~:text=The%20double%20opt%2Din%20campaign,to%20confirm%20their%20email%20address.

Comment: This is only one of multiple options for doing double opt-in. The more standard one is using a regular signup form, and then enable an automated DOI email, as described here: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_double_optin_classiclist.htm&type=5